# If $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are bounded intervals with $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$, then $\sup(A \cap B) = \min\{\sup A, \sup B\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I am looking for hint on the question:

> If $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are bounded intervals with $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$, then $\sup(A \cap B) = \min\{\sup A, \sup B\}$.

So far, I have shown that $\beta = \min\{\sup A, \sup B\}$ is an upper bound for $A \cap B$. Hence, $\sup(A \cap B) \leq \beta$. Where I get stuck is showing this must be the least upper bound. I wish to show that $\sup(A \cap B) \geq \beta$, by supposing $\sup(A \cap B) < \beta$, and finding a contradiction by finding some element $x \in A \cap B$ such that $x > \sup(A \cap B)$. I think I need to use the assumption that $A, B$ (and thus so is $A \cap B$) are intervals, but I am not sure how if this is the case.

This is where I am stuck and would appreciate a hint on how to move forward. Thank you.

Comment: It seems very easy to argue directly, by writing $A = (a, b)$ and $B = (c, d)$.

Comment: This question is tricky! Good work so far - it looks like you're doing well at being rigorous about things that seem obvious. I would proceed by first assuming WLOG that $\sup A \le \sup B$. Now when you assume $\sup(A \cap B) < \beta = \sup A$, you can find an element $x \in A$ such that $\sup(A \cap B) < x < \sup A$. Then we also have $x < \sup B$, so there is a $y \in B$ with $x < y$. Then you can conclude $x \in B$, which is absurd. I've left some gaps there for you to fill in! You will need to make copious use of the definition of $\sup$, and the property of being an interval.

Comment: As Arctic Char mentions, you could also proceed by using the fact that bounded intervals in $\Bbb R$ are all of the form $(a, b)$ or $(a, b]$ or $[a, b)$ or $[a, b]$, where $a$ is the $\inf$, and $b$ is the $\sup$ of the interval. But probably this wasn't intended, given how you're arguing so far and it would require a proof. Not to mention, there are a LOT of cases to check there!

Comment: It suffices to consider the case of open intervals, as  $A\cap B$ is smaller than 8n other cases and we are after $\ge$ inequality.

Comment: You are correct that $A, B$ being intervals is necessary for equality to hold. For example, if $A = (0,2)$ and $B = (0,1) \cup (3,4)$, we have $\sup A = 2, \sup B = 4, \sup A\cap B = 1$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc - it *almost* suffices, but open intervals miss the case $[a,b] \cap [b,c]$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's right, I have missed that case. We can restrict to intervals such that the intersection of their interiors is nonempty. The remaining case can be inspected by hand.